# I want to disable a forgot password button for 30 seconds after the user has clicked it once, to avoid multiple trigger of email for forgot password

Tags: javascript

hi i have to disable forgot password button for 30 secs soon after the user has clicked it once & an alert should show him to 'Please try again after 30 seconds' This is to avoid multiple trigger of mails providing user a temporary password. after 30 secs the button should be enabled again

I have tried using setTimeout to disable button for 30 seconds after click.. i am confused on how to use it. Please help me on this

```
  <button>
    <a id="forgotPassword" class="cursorPointer loginlables">
      Forgot Password?
    </a>
  </button>
```

User should be able to click forgot password button once and then error message should display if he tries to click button again within 30 seconds of first click.

Comment: Where is your code? What have you tried? What line is causing the error?

Comment: Please edit your question, put your code inside the question and not in the comments.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We will help you here, but you need to have a go at writing some code first. If you don't know how to write the code, you might need to do some learning first

Comment: @mikkel   I am posting a question first time in Stockoverflow and i am a new user. I will take your suggestions and going forward try to improve on it..please dont give negative flag for my question...

Comment: @Vijay.vashist my apologies for what may seem like unfair criticism, but the only code you have posted is html, and you haven't posted your js - which is actually where the problem is, right? It's really hard to provide advice on only a description of your problem with no code. If you read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask it may be clearer. And part of what you will read in there is that we don't write code for you (which you appear to be asking for). I hope this explains why I have downvoted your question.

Comment: @Mikkel i understood your point. but if you are downvoting a person who is new to the application sounds unfair & will create a negative thought in persons mind. I know its my mistake not pasting js code but give some time before judging anyone

Comment: Well, if you want some understanding, how about posting your js code now to rescue your reputation?

Comment: @mikkel already my question has been answered by few people. Now if i put my js code there is no use.. If you are so much concerned about it.. you can post your solution to this instead of doing bla bla bla...

Comment: @Vijay.vashist part of the way that stack overflow works is not only to solve your problem, but also to provide a long term reference for other people, so that if they have a similar problem, they might find this question and answers, and it may solve their need without having to compose a question. So if the question is complete and well formed, it becomes a good question for all to see. It's not just me being pedantic, it's the way that SO is intended to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up a global variable which holds the time the user clicked the button and an action - like sending a reminder - has been initiated. Everytime you enter the callback for the button's click handler, you compare this time to the current time and if it's difference is smaller than 30 seconds show an alert dialog.

Javascript provides the **Date** object for time and date operations.

```js
var lastCall = 0;
var timeToWait = 30;

function doAction() {
  var timePassed = Date.now() - lastCall;
  if (timePassed >= timeToWait * 1000) {
    console.log("send email");
    lastCall = Date.now();
  } else {
    alert("Please wait " + parseInt(timeToWait - (timePassed / 1000)) + " seconds");
  }
}
document.getElementById("forgotPassword").addEventListener("click", doAction);
```

```html
<button id="forgotPassword">
Forgot password
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response. I will try this out for sure. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by setTimeout Function

```
document.getElementById("forgotPassword").addEventListener('click', function(){
        alert("Button is disabled for 30sec")
        document.getElementById("forgotPassword").disabled = true;
        setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById("forgotPassword").disabled = false;},30000);
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

in your future posts, please add your code so we can help you better.

First of all, I've always been told using setTimeout isn't a good habit in JS, so keep in mind my solution probably isn't the best available, but that's one.

```js
function myfunction() {
  btn = document.getElementById('btn');
  if (btn.innerHTML === 'Click me') {
    console.log('Clicked !')
    btn.innerHTML = 'Wait a bit plz';
     setTimeout(() => {
        btn.innerHTML = 'Click me';
     }, 5000);
  }
}
```

```html
<button id='btn' onclick='myfunction()'>Click me</button>
```

Here i'm using the text of my button to decide if it can be clicked or not, but you can create a boolean or use a class, as you wish.
The idea still is the same, check if your button is clickable, if it is, make it unclickable for a given period (wich you can achieve by using `setTimeout(() => {}, 5000);`.